# Cancel onclick event in IE5

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, event-handling, dom-events

I want to cancel inline `onclick` event

```
<p id="demo" onclick="alert(1234)"></p>
```

in certain condition, so I am using a global `onclick` event to conditionally overwrite this event.

```
this.document.attachEvent('onClick', function(e){
        if(--some condition--){
            --code to cancel onclick event--
        }
});
```

the question is what to write in `--code to cancel onclick event--`.

I have tried `e.preventDefault(); e.cancelBubble = true; return false;` however nothing works.

Please notice that the browser need to be IE5.

Comment: IE5 ?!?!?  Who are you developing for?